# I would like to visualize the third order interaction fitted with thin-plate regression splines

Tags: r, spline

I am a beginner of R so it may be a simple question.

I am now trying to fit a 4-dimensional point using thin-plate regression splines. One variable is a target variable and three variables are an explanatory variable.

I made a model with third order interaction and fitted the data to this.

```
library(mgcv)
dat <- read.csv('../data//data.csv')
model <- gam(Y ~ s(x1, x2, x3), data=dat)
```

By giving x3, I want to visualize a three-dimensional graph of spline curve or estimated contour plot, but how do I do it?

It will be very helpful if you can answer.
Thanks.

---

This is the sample data.

```
n = 100
x1 <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 100)
x2 <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 100)
x3 <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 100)

Y = numeric(n)
for(i in 1:n){
    Y[i] <- x1[i]**0.5*x2[i]**2*x3[i]/10000
}

dat = data.frame(Y=Y, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3)
```

I do thin-plane regression spline using this dat.

```
model <- gam(Y ~ s(x1, x2, x3, k= 50), data=dat)
```

Then, I would like to obtain a fitting curve of three-dimensional thin-plane regression spline or contour plot estimated by regression spline when x3 = 25, for example.

Comment: Can you make a fully reproducible example with sample data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with reference to the answer of d0d0.

```
n=100
const=25

x = y = seq(0, n, 1)
f = function(x,y){
    dtmp <- data.frame(x1=(x), x2=(y), x3=(const))
    pred <- predict.gam(model, dtmp)
}
z = outer(x, y, f)
contour(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a contour plot, you can use contour(x, y, z, ...). z is your data Matrix (in your case, Y[x1,x2, ], x and y are index vectors from 0 to 1 with a length of nrow(Y[x1,x2, ]) and ncol(Y[x1,x2, ]).

You should be able to use it similar to:

```
contour( x = seq(0, 1, length.out = length(x1)), y = seq(0, 1, length.out = length(x2)), z = Y[x1,x2, ] )
```